# What is the difference between FUNCALL and #'function-name in common lisp?

Tags: function, common-lisp

I am reading through a book for homework, and I understand that using #' is treating the variable as a function instead of a variable. But I am a little hazy on FUNCALL. I understand that lisp makes object out of variables, so is the function name just a 'pointer' (may be a bad word, but hopefully you get what I mean), in which case you use #' to invoke it, or is funcall the only way to invoke them? ex.

```
(defun plot (fn min max step)
(loop for i from min to max by step do
      (loop repeat (funcall fn i) do (format t "*"))
      (format t "~%")))
```

couldn't I just do:

```
(defun plot (fn min max step)
(loop for i from min to max by step do
      (loop repeat #'(fn i) do (format t "*"))
      (format t "~%")))
```

I guess my confusion lies in what exactly is in the function names. When I read the book, it said that the variable's value is what will be the function object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#'function-name` is `(function function-name)`. Nothing is called, evaluating either results in the function associated with `function-name` (the object representing the function). `funcall` is used to call functions.

See [funcall](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm#funcall) and [function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm) in the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/).

Sample session using both:

```
CL-USER> (defun square (x) (* x x))
SQUARE
CL-USER> #'square
#<FUNCTION SQUARE>
CL-USER> (function square)
#<FUNCTION SQUARE>
CL-USER> (funcall #'square 3)
9
CL-USER> (funcall 'square 3)
9
```

The second invocation of `funcall` works because it also accepts a symbol as function designator (see the link for `funcall` above for details).

Answer (score 9):

The `#'` and `funcall` notations are needed in Common Lisp because this language is a so-called "Lisp-2" where a given symbol can have two separate and unrelated main "meanings" normally listed as

1. When used as first element of a form it means a function
2. When used in any other place it means a variable

These are approximate explanations, as you will see in the following example that "first element of a form" and "any other place" are not correct definitions.

Consider for example:

[image: lisp-2]

the above code prints `144`... it may seem surprising at first but the reason is that the same name `square` is used with two different meanings: the function that given an argument returns the result of multiplying the argument by itself and the local variable square with value 12.

The first and third uses of the name `square` the meaning is the **function** named `square` and I've painted the name with red color. The second and fourth uses instead are about a **variable** named `square` and are painted in blue instead.

How can Common Lisp decide which is which? the point is the position... after `defun` it's clearly in this case a function name, like it's a function name in the first part of `(square square)`. Likewise as first element of a list inside a `let` form it's clearly a variable name and it's also a variable name in the second part of `(square square)`.

This looks pretty psychotic... doesn't it? Well there is indeed some splitting in the Lisp community about if this dual meaning is going to make things simpler or more complex and it's one of the main differences between Common Lisp and Scheme.

Without getting into the details I'll just say that this apparently crazy choice has been made to make Lisp macros more useful, providing enough hygiene to make them working nicely without the added complexity and the removed expressiveness power of full hygienic macros. For sure it's a complication that makes it harder to explain the language to whoever is learning it (and that's why Scheme is considered a better (simpler) language for teaching) but many expert lispers think that it's a good choice that makes the Lisp language a better tool for real problems.

Also in human languages the context plays an important role anyway and there it's not a serious problem for humans that sometimes the very same word can be used with different meanings (e.g. as a noun or as a verb like "California is the state I live in" or "State your opinion").

Even in a Lisp-2 you need however to use functions as values, for example passing them as parameters or storing them into a data structure, or you need to use values as functions, for example calling a function that has been received as parameter (your plot case) or that has been stored somewhere. This is where `#'` and `funcall` come into play...

`#'foo` is indeed just a shortcut for `(function foo)`, exactly like `'x` is a shortcut for `(quote x)`. This "function" thing is a special form that given a name (`foo` in this case) returns the associated function as a value, that you can store in variables or pass around:

```
(defvar *fn* #'square)
```

in the above code for example the variable `*fn*` is going to receive the function defined before. A function value can be manipulated as any other value like a string or a number.

`funcall` is the opposite, allowing to call a function not using its name but by using a value...

```
(print (funcall *fn* 12))
```

the above code will display 144... because the function that was stored in the variable `*fn*` now is being called passing 12 as argument.

If you know the "C" programming language an analogy is considering `(let ((p #'square))...)` like taking the address of the function `square` (as with `{ int (*p)(int) = &square; ...}`) and instead `(funcall p 12)` is like calling a function using a pointer (as with `(*p)(12)` that "C" allows to be abbreviated to `p(12)`).

The admittely confusing part in Common Lisp is that you can have both a function named `square` and a variable named `square` in the same scope and the variable will not hide the function. `funcall` and `function` are two tools you can use when you need to use the value of a variable as a function or when you want a function as a value, respectively.

Comment: I think that your explanation could be less « mystic » if you've used the word `namespace` instead of the vague word `meaning`. CL is a Lisp-2 which means a symbol can appear in both namespaces with different value in each. i.e. the symbol `foo` can have the value 42 in the value namespace (you can look at its value with `symbol-value`) and it can also have the value of `(lambda (x) (1+ x))` in the function namespace (`symbol-function`).

Comment: Thank you for that. I do wonder. In your case, you passed the function into a global variable. If you have the function in there, could you not also do (\*fn\* 12) ? or is that only for the square function, which exists as a function?

Comment: @Andy: the form `(*fn* 12)` means in common lisp "call the function that is named `*fn*` passing 12 as parameter"... the function being called is logically fixed and could even be inlined by the compiler: is the function `(defun *fn* (x) ...)`. The variable named in the same way is another unrelated thing and can contain any value... for example a number, a string or even the address of a function. The form `(funcall *fn* 12)` means "call the function whose address is contained in the variable named `*fn*`". On the other side `#'square` means, more or less, "the address of function 'square'".